# C.VIM not working

Tags: c++, vim

I have a simple question (that I don't seem to be able to answer),

I am a new VIM/Linux user, and since I do c++ development I decided to install the C.VIM plugin to speed up my development time. The problem is, it says in the plug-in (c++) menu that to do a switch statement I have to write **\ss** (for me the leader is "**,**", so it's "**,ss**") but when I do this it just puts me in insert mode and nothing happens. I know the plugin is well set up because when I open a new c++ file it generates a comment box where I can give the description of the program.

I would love it if I would be able to use the shortcuts, because using the menu just losses the point of using vim.

Oh and please, just keep in mind that I am new to vim, I still have hard time figuring out what means `<c-r> + TAB` (which is, if i'm not mistaking "`ctrl-r <tab>`"), so if you could just try to explain the solution clearly without to much jargon I would appreciate it. (while i'm here, does anyone know of a good vim tutorial where I could understands all of the vim jargon, thanks!)

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: If you’re still having this issue, come see us at [vi.se]! We have a lot of experts that might be able to help you diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0):

I use this cheat sheet:

http://www.worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line to .vimrc and

```
helptags ~/.vim/bundle/c.vim/doc
```

Note: I have pointed to my c.vim doc and I use bundle, it may differ for you :)